# Write List of Jsons using Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm staring at a file I'm not sure what to do with.  File (data.txt) that contains a list of dictionaries like this:

```
{'name': 'jerry', 'internalip1': '192.168.1.1', 'externalip1': '1.1.1.1', 'internalip2': '192.168.1.2', 'externalip2': '2.2.2.2', 'port1': '5451', 'port2': '5450', 'port3': '', 'port4': '', 'port5': '', 'port6': ''}
{'name': 'chris', 'internalip1': '192.168.2.1', 'externalip1': '3.3.3.3', 'internalip2': '192.168.3.5', 'externalip2': '4.4.4.4', 'port1': '1234', 'port2': '', 'port3': '5671', 'port4': '5672', 'port5': '80', 'port6': '443'}
...
...
```

How can I create a new text file (data_updated.txt) that looks like this:

```
edit "externalip1--internalip1 Port port1"
set extip externalip1
set mappedip "internalip1"
set portforward enable
set extport port1
set mappedport port1

edit "externalip1--internalip1 Port port2"
set extip externalip1
set mappedip "internalip1"
set portforward enable
set extport port2
set mappedport port2
...
...
```

Comment: Hey, could you show us any attempt at solving this issue? We need to see what your problem is. Can you read the file? How do you read it? What have you done so far?

Comment: That's the thing I'm not sure where to began.  I know I need a for loop and f strings but not sure how to write it

Comment: It says Jsons in your title, but there is nothing to do with JSON in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
with open('data.txt') as data_file:
    lines = data_file.readlines()
    output = []
    for line in lines:
        data = eval(line.strip())
        output.extend([
            f"edit \"{data['externalip1']}--{data['externalip1']} Port {data['port1']}\"\n",
            f"set extip externalip1\n",
            f"set mappedip \"{data['internalip1']}\"\n",
            f"set portforward enable\n",
            f"set extport {data['port1']}\n",
            f"set mappedport {data['port1']}\n",
            '\n',
            # ...
        ])
    with open('data_updated.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.writelines(output)
```

Comment: This is only doing it for one of the items

Comment: No. It iterates over all items. if you want to write more attrs to output file, you can put them after this line: `# ...`

Comment: did it work for you?